# Error thrown when using “return” on Submit event function call

Tags: javascript

I’m in the process of creating a simple application in Electron that allows you to add tasks to a list. However, it shouldn’t allow you to add empty tasks.

The following script is a minimum, verifiable version of what I’m using inside the Renderer JS file.

```
const taskForm = document.querySelector('form');
taskForm.addEventListener('submit', addTask);

function addTask(event)
{
  const formInput = taskForm.querySelector('input[type="text"]');
  const taskName = formInput.value;
  formInput.value = "";

  if (!taskName || taskName.length === 0)
  {
    console.log("Empty"); 
    return; //It doesn't seem to like this return. No idea why.
  }

 //Task element is created and added

  event.preventDefault();
}
```

I’ve also put together a JSFiddle, for those who want to mess around with the issue in code: https://jsfiddle.net/bts22a34/ It seems to throw an issue here too, despite being outside Electron.

Whenever it hits the return function, it throws the following error:

"Error: No such module: atom_renderer_v8_util"

From adding a breakpoint just before the "if" statement, it seems to successfully complete the return, hit the end of the function, and then throw the error.

If I send in a non-empty string, it skips past the if statement successfully and completes the function with no error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From messing around with it again just now, it seems to be an issue with regards to “event.preventDefault” not being run if you go through the if statement.

```
const taskList = document.querySelector('div');
const taskForm = document.querySelector('form');
taskForm.addEventListener('submit', addTask);

id = -1;

function addTask(event)
{
  const formInput = taskForm.querySelector('input[type="text"]');
  const taskName = formInput.value;
  formInput.value = "";

  if (!taskName || taskName.length === 0)
  {
    console.log("Empty"); 
  }

  else
  {
    //Task element is created and added
  }

  event.preventDefault();
}
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bts22a34/

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. If you have another question you should post a new question, or update your original one.

Comment: @Jamiec But it fixes the error I originally had, which was that "return" threw an error. It seems this may have been because "event.preventDefault" wasn't run.

Comment: Oh, ok. So this is both question and answer. That's fine. But having the line `If someone could explain why the below snippet works` in the *answer* sounds like you're asking another question - and made it seem like you thought this place works like other "tech forums" you might be used to. It doesnt operate that way. :)

Comment: Ive edited out the part where you ask another question. If you wanted to ask that question, feel free to post another question. PS. Welcome to SO, you seem pretty new

Comment: @Jamiec I see what you mean now, and thanks for clarifying. :)